# How to Make a CountDown Timer Java

Tags: java, timer, countdown

I was developing this small application. In a JFrame, I have 3 JSpinners to select Hours, Minutes and Seconds. In addition there is a JButton to Start the Time. When I press it It should Count Down the Time that I selected using JSpinners. There is a JLabel to show the CountDown time. I have searched many posts in StackOverFlow but nothing Helped me. This is a code I found in a Post and It is not working at all. Can anyone please Help???

```
private void countDownTimer() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread thread = new Thread();
    int hours = (int) jSpinner1.getValue();
    int minutes = (int) jSpinner2.getValue();
    int seconds = (int) jSpinner3.getValue();

    for (int a = seconds; a <= 0; a--) {

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Can anyone please Help me???

Comment: May be you can make use of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)

Answer (score 1):

There are many mistakes implementation wise.

There is no need to throw an Exception on the function

```
throws InterruptedException
```

To create a new `Thread` you have to provide the code to be run in said thread (AKA `Runnable`):

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            // Your code here
        }
    });
thread.start();
```

Apart from that, I cannot understand the goal of the following code:

```
for (int a = seconds; a <= 0; a--) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

What are you trying to achieve by counting down the seconds? What about the hours and minutes?

I will provide a solution that you will have to complete for the code to work as you want as it will countdown the whole seconds sum. If you want to update the hour and minute values you will have to work on that yourself.

```
private void countDownTimer() {

    final int hours = (int) jSpinner1.getValue();
    final int minutes = (int) jSpinner2.getValue();
    final int seconds = (int) jSpinner3.getValue();

    // Create Thread not to block UI
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable () {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Calculate total seconds to count down
            int countdownSeconds = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds;

            // Count down to 0 and print it on the console
            for (int i = countdownSeconds ; i >= 0; i--) {

                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch (InterruptedException e) {}

                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    });
    // Start the Thread
    thread.start();
}
```

Hope you find it usefull. Feel free to ask questions on the comments.

Comment: Thank you so much @UDKOX
I will let you know If I have furthur issues with your code

Comment: Here you have made time (Hours, Minutes and Seconds) to Seconds. If it Prints the Seconds as System.out.println(i);  in the sample, It will prints only the Seconds from top to zero. As in the picture I have attached, all I need is When I press Start, the seconds should reduce to zero until the Minutes and Hours are becoming zeros like in a stopwatch. Any Idea How can I do that?

Comment: @CodeBae I fixed your code and added explanations for you. You only have to change the *for* loop to get your desired output. If you can't do it by yourself maybe you should read some books on programming first. It's useless for me to do it if you are just going to copy/paste the answer.

Comment: @CodeBae True, forgot to add the 'Exception' for the sentence. Should work now.

Comment: It takes hours to print the value. I think you have something wrong with the code. BTW Thanks @UDKOX

Comment: @CodeBae I am sorry, there was a mistake on the comparison. I could not try the code myself I copied yours and did not check. Can you try now ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on your question because I don't have 50 points, so I will have to write an answer with a question here.

You are saying that the code above is not working. What exactly is not working? What are the symptoms and what do you expect to happen?

One of the problems is that you are iterating over seconds only, ignoring minutes and hours completely. The other one is that you are creating a thread that is not used at all. The third one is that you are invoking `Thread.sleep(1000)` inside the for loop, but I am not sure if you are aware that it would block the Thread completely until it's finished.

Firstly, the for loop should start with:

```
for (int a = hours * 3600 + 60 * minutes + seconds; a >= 0; a--)
```

Secondly, `Thread thread = new Thread();` is not used at all.

Thirdy, `Thread.sleep(1000)` will block the current thread until it's finished.

And lastly, your condition is saying `a <= 0` instead of `a >= 0`.

So one of the ways you can adjust the above code is:

```
private void countDownTimer() throws InterruptedException {
    int hours = (int) jSpinner1.getValue();
    int minutes = (int) jSpinner2.getValue();
    int seconds = (int) jSpinner3.getValue();

    for (int a = hours * 3600 + 60 * minutes + seconds; a >= 0; a--) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

This is assuming that the 'not working' means it's ignoring minutes and hours.

The other solution is to create a new thread with a callback function, that will be invoked once the countdown timer reaches zero:

```
public class CountDownRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final int hours;
    private final int minutes;
    private final int seconds;

    public CountDownRunnable(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
      this.hours = hours;
      this.minutes = minutes;
      this.seconds = seconds;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int a = hours * 3600 + 60 * minutes + seconds; a >= 0; a--) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(a);
        }

        // Here goes your code that will be invoked once the timer reaches zero...
    }
}
```

Then your method would look like this:

```
private void countDownTimer() throws InterruptedException {
    (new Thread(new HelloRunnable())).start();
}
```